# secure link of videostreaming file

Tags: video, video-streaming

i have AVI video on apache server. I have PHP script generating url to this video file.
This url is used as mediasource in embeded code of Windows media player in my HTML.
Everithing is O.k. but link to this file is public. Everybody can read this video.

My vision is have DB of users and after login to my page user is able play this video resp. link.

How do that?

Can i use php to resolve it?

Answer (score -1):

Similar question here [embedding-image-video-stream-into-webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194941/embedding-image-video-stream-into-webpage)

> I'm trying to create a PHP webpage that allow the visitor to see a
>   video stream or an image coming from a webcam without allowing the
>   visitors to grab it's original URL/URI.

It looks like we've the same problem.